# Is there a way to add additional stickers to Telegram in Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, telegram

I am running [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) v.2.2.30 on a [BQ Aquaris 4.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BQ_Aquaris_E4.5) with Ubuntu OTA 12. However, the answer is probably device independent.

On Android the corresponding menu entry is `Stickers --> Trending Stickers`, where you can download additional stickers.

PS: I found out that these stickers are [WebP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) files stored under `/Device/custom/click/com.ubuntu.telegram/current/stickers/telegram` and named 01.webp till 35.webp.

Comment: I didn't find any easy way to add stickers from the Touch app itself, but I added stickers from the desktop client/ Telegram Web, then they showed up in Touch app too.

Comment: @pomsky Please add this as an answer. It is a nice workaround and I never would have thought that it will work, but it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any easy way to add stickers in the Touch app itself, but if you add stickers in the desktop client or [Telegram Web](https://web.telegram.org/), the same will show up in Touch app too.

Comment: I did not find the setting in telegram web. The desktop client however worked fine.

Comment: @bruni If you have the url of the sticker pack (example: https://telegram.me/addstickers/EvilMinds), then following the link you can open the pack in Telegram Web (unless the desktop client is already set as the default handler of tg links in you browser settings). There you'll be able to add the pack to your collection.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an additional workaround that requires somebody sending you a sticker from the set you would like to install.

1. Swipe the sticker left
2. tap on the info button
3. you get to see the whole sticker set that this sticker belongs to and below you will get the option to install.

[image: scaled Image of a sticker set as seen after pressing the info button]